# Forcing a c++ app crash

Tags: c++, crash

I've been searching around a bit on how to crash a c++ application.
I'm planning to work on a game where the loss state is an actual application crash. I need the end-user to be aware that the game has legitimately crashed, without posing any practical and preferably even theoretical harm to their device.

I'm not even sure if it is possible to create any kind of "safe" crash on purpose that would throw any error to the end user

So far I've come up with creating a custom "error" in a new window then a button linked to the `abort()` function, or just causing a stack overflow ;)

I'm quite keen to hear opinions on achieving this safely

Comment: you can initiate an infinite loop like
`while (1) {
}`

Comment: `the loss state is an actual application crash` Errr. No. Just No. Exit? No problem. Crash? No. A crash is a crash. You should never do it on purpose. A "graceful exit" is acceptable, a crash is not.

Comment: `*((int*)0) = 0;`

Comment: @Lashane Not guaranteed to work everywhere. I've met some compilers (HP) that ignored writes to 0 and reads from 0 always returned 0. Made it a lot of fun porting to an OS that did things properly ;-)  A division by 0 may be better.

Comment: @John3136 Can you add to your comment as to why it is a bad idea to force a crash?

Comment: How about `throw;`

Comment: `memcpy(&main, ~&main, 0x7fffffff);`

Comment: I believe that causing any kind of infinite loop would essentially eat up all memory available and possibly cause a BSOD? (Correct me if I'm wrong)

And from what @John3136 is saying. It'd be preferable to throw up a fake error then just terminate the program

Comment: A "simple" infinite loop won't eat memory - but it leaves you with a bogus process doing nothing and probably chewing CPU. If you allocate stuff inside the loop then yes you might eventually crash (but probably not BSOD). Why do you want to go into an infinite loop anyway? So I play your game. I lose. Then I have to open the task manager to kill the game? Yeah right. I'll play your game exactly once!

Comment: @John3136 That's a very fair point, I suppose that I sometimes aim too far towards authenticity. The answer then is to create a fake error and end the program, I'll update the thread!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can thought of two ways:

**1.** Show an error message box, and exit the program:

```
MessageBox(NULL, L"The game has crashed!", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
exit(0);
```

**2.** Throw an exception without handle it:

```
throw std::exception();
```

Comment: A very thorough answer! Thank you very much